# Icons (fontawesome, material icons) with blinking !/? issue

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I never had this kind of problem - and I don't know why..

some icons are missing and appearing blinking with "?/!"

what is happening?

Its a submit button. I have the same icon in another button - and it's ok there.

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" 
      class="btn btn-inv btn-lg" style="--h: #822584" 
      onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('classid').value='WAI-04'">

    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> SIGN!
</button>
```

any idea?

tks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the newest version of Font-Awesome, `fa` is no longer a valid class.  It has been replaced with `fas` (solid), and `fab` (brands). For a thumbs up, you would use:

```
<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
```

Here is the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js) if you want to learn more.

Comment: tks @jakattk123!

Comment: @DANIEL Not a problem!  I actually had the same issue not too long ago.